# Make Onboarding only appear once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate

I know there are loads of questions like this on Stackoverflow but I just cant seem to get this right. Basically I have code that will print correctly weather or not it is the first time the app has been launched or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("Not first launch.")
    }
        
    else {
        print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardingSB")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    return true
}
```

I just don't understand why it wont open on the onboarding view controller on the first attempt.

The initial view controller is the 'Main View Controller'

Main Storyboard ID: Main

Onboarding Storyboard ID: onboardingSB

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` inside AppDelegate:

```
if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "notFirstInApp") == false){
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "notFirstInApp")
    //Here you can show storyboard that you have to launch at first launch
}else{
    //Here you can show storyboard that you have to launch after first launch
}
```

This works fine.

Like in your case it will be,

```
if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "notFirstInApp") == false){
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "notFirstInApp")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardingSB")
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}else{
   //Here you can show storyboard that you have to launch after first launch
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response! Im sorry but I just tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: am I doing something wrong? it just goes straight to the main view controller

Comment: @mick1996 inside if condition you have to initialise controller that you have to direct at first launch and inside else initialise controller that you have to show after first launch ("Not First Launch").

Comment: @mick1996 I have updated my answer, please check now. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your help but your updated answer still doesn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

for some reason I am unable to do this in the app delegate. I have found a way around it tho.

I first set the initial view controller to the onboarding screen

Then I added this to the view will appear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        if Core.shared.isNewUser(){
            Core.shared.notNewUser()
            
            print("new user")
        }
            
        else{
            print("existing user")
            
            let mainAppViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
            
            if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                let sceneDelegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate,
                let window = sceneDelegate.window{
                
                window.rootViewController = mainAppViewController
                
                UIView.transition(with: window,
                                  duration: 0.25,
                                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                  animations: nil,
                                  completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Core class:

```
class Core{
    
    static let shared = Core()
    
    func isNewUser() -> Bool{
        return !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isNewUser")
    }
    
    func notNewUser(){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isNewUser")
    }
```

Credit to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GFgmjZ4r2c&t=434s

Comment: Well, that's wrong too. The place to do it is in the _scene delegate_. That way, the wrong view controller is _never_ the root view controller. See my https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample/blob/master/RegistrationExample/AppDelegate.swift for an example.

Comment: @matt thank you for your response! I understand your point I will try out your solution. does the fact that I am using UIKit and not SwiftUI affect me using scene Delegate over App Delegate

Comment: No, I'm totally UIKit.